# Node, serve premade gzip files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, gzip, bundle

Ok, I have a problem concerning gzip files. I make a gzip files beforehand using webpack so they are premade and ready to be served if browser supports it, no need for dynamic compression in the moment user asks for them.

I have four bundle files, 2 are from the client side (static files) and 2 from server side files. For both of them I have bundle.js and bundle.js.gz

I can serve client(static files) normally using express-static-gzip plugin but I don't know how to serve premade server side bundle.js.gz My code looks like this.

```
...

import expressStaticGzip from 'express-static-gzip'
const app = express()

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'server', 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(expressStaticGzip(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'dist'), {
  indexFromEmptyFile: false,
  enableBrotli: false,
  maxAge: '1y',
}))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
  return next()
})

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index')
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Node server is listening on port 3000`)
})

...
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. My solution was to use nginx and serve dynamically this in gzip format. That is the only thing that is gziped on the fly. Everything else is premade and served when needed.